# Setting transformations to greyscale with libpng

Tags: c++, libpng

I am using libpng to read an image. The image itself has 4 channels (rgba), with 8 bits for channel. I want to read it as a greyscale image, preferably black and white (1 bit per pixel), but even 8 bits per pixel would be an improvement.

To that end, i have written function, as follows:

```
extern "C" void cuttingStream::set_image_transformations_in_grayscale( pngImageInfo* info,pngDataStructures* png)
{
    //alpha channel is removed
    if (info->color_type & PNG_COLOR_MASK_ALPHA != PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY)
        png_set_strip_alpha(png->png_struct_field);
    //switch to rgb is completed
    if (info->color_type & PNG_COLOR_MASK_COLOR != PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY)
        png_set_rgb_to_gray(png->png_struct_field,1,NULL,NULL);
    png_read_update_info(png->png_struct_field, png->png_info_field);

    info -> rowbytes = png_get_rowbytes(png->png_struct_field, png->png_info_field);
    //bits per CHANNEL! note: not per pixel!
    info->bitdepth   = png_get_bit_depth(png->png_struct_field, png->png_info_field);
    //Number of channels
    info->channels   = png_get_channels(png->png_struct_field, png->png_info_field);
    //Color type. (RGB, RGBA, Luminance, luminance alpha... palette... etc)
    info->color_type = png_get_color_type(png->png_struct_field, png->png_info_field);
}
```

pngDataStructures is my own struct that holds things such as png_structp, png_infop and pointers to custom read function. pngImageInfo holds some information about image that is interesting to me, as it can be seen in the code.

The problem is, after the code executes, number of channels does not change. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

operator precedence problem:

//alpha channel is removed
if ( **(** info->color_type & PNG_COLOR_MASK_ALPHA **)**  != PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY)

the precedence of operator **&** is less than operator **!=**